# Loop through custom taxonomies and display posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy

While I've been able to get this working for normal WP categories I've been unable to get it working for custom taxonomies.

I'd like to loop through each custom taxonomy (categories in my case) and produce a number of posts for each.

An example of the output would be:

```
Category 1

post from category one
post from category one

read more category one


Category 2

post from category two
post from category two

read more category two
```

Of course it would repeat through any available taxonomy for the custom post type.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. When you ask " loop through each custom taxonomy" do you mean " loop through the terms of each custom taxonomy?" Also, when you ask to "produce a number of posts" does "produce" mean insert new instances of a post type into the database or generate HTML for the post type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought I would provide another answer as the above one is a little hacky, also I added another layer that gets all taxonomies for a post_type.

```
$post_type = 'post';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
            //Do you general query loop here  
        endwhile; endif;

    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

It would be recommended to add each post found to a `$post__not_in` array, so you could pass that to the `WP_Query` to prevent duplicate posts coming through.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this ?

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post type name', 'Taxonomy slug' => $term->slug ) ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[How to create Custom Taxonomy loop](http://techsloution4u.com/code-snippet/how-to-create-custom-taxonomy-loop.html#.UEEEkyLcB2g)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this function in your functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'display_all_products_from_all_categories' ) ) {

    function display_all_products_from_all_categories() {

        // Get all the categories for Custom Post Type Product
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product', 
            'orderby' => 'id', 
            'order' => 'ASC' 
        );

        $categories = get_categories( $args );

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
                <!-- Get the category title -->
                <h3 class="title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>

                <!-- Get the category description -->
                <div class="description">
                    <p><?php echo category_description( get_category_by_slug($category->slug)->term_id ); ?></p>
                </div>

                <ul class="mhc-product-grid">

                    <?php
                        // Get all the products of each specific category
                        $product_args = array(
                            'post_type'     => 'product',
                            'orderby'      => 'id',
                            'order'         => 'ASC',
                            'post_status'   => 'publish',
                            'category_name' => $category->slug //passing the slug of the current category
                        );

                        $product_list = new WP_Query ( $product_args );

                    ?>

                    <?php while ( $product_list -> have_posts() ) : $product_list -> the_post(); ?>

                        <li class="product <?php the_field( 'product_flavor' ); ?>">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-link">

                                <!-- if the post has an image, show it -->
                                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img', 'alt' => get_the_title() ) ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <!-- custom fields: product_flavor, product_description ... -->
                                <h3 class="title <?php the_field( 'product_flavor' ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p class="description"><?php the_field( 'product_description' ); ?></p>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it from anywhere in your template with:

```
display_all_products_from_all_categories();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this example; create a own loop for your taxonomie. You can also use this in a foreach-loop to use all categories. Or you must create an own sql-query.

```
<?php
$taxonomies = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'YOUR_TAXONOMIE', '', '', '');
$taxonomies = explode('>', $taxonomies);
$taxonomies = $taxonomies[1];
$myq = new WP_Query('your_taxonomie = '.$taxonomies); 
if ($myq->have_posts()) : while ($myq->have_posts()) : $myq->the_post(); // the loop ?>

            <?php the_title();?>
            <?php the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; else:?>

<?php endif;?>
```